# Disabling Pantheon Mail

Tags: pantheon-mail, release-hera

I really tried to like the Mail program that ships with the OS - ran it for ~4 months.

I installed Thunderbird last week.

How do I disable pantheon-mail from starting on first login? I thought it might be the notifications settings for mail but they are turned off and I still get pantheon-mail appearing in the dock.

Thunderbird is set to the default mail app in settings -> apps.

Did I miss another setting or do I have to resort to running 'killall pantheon-mail' as a login start script?

[problem migrated from Juno to Hera if it matters]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uninstall it completely via app center?

I'm also on the way to either ditch the mail program and return to Thunderbird or to leave it as is... I've been a Thunderbird user for so many years, so this is kind of refreshing.

Sadly, I cannot say the same for their music Noise app that is just slow, unstable tra$h at the moment.

Comment: Oh - ha! Yes, I can just uninstall it. Thanks - I will do that.

I've spent a lot of time searching for a good music app. I settled on Lollypop (latest version as a flatpak). It's a great program and doesn't look ugly or out of place in elementary.

Comment: Oh, thank you for that! Lollypop certainly looks refreshing and interesting. I might stick with it, even though artist/cover images seem to load sporadically. But eventually it will populate all, I think. Lollypop has an EQ so that's a big + for me.  Currently I'm using Melody, looks nice and is a good player. 

Kind of strange that Elementary devs made one of the least stable players I tried. What's worse, people were saying it was broken/extremely slow with import since beginning of this year. Did they listen? No. Until then, it will remain uninstalled, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

System settings > Applications > Startup . Click on the mail icon and then the "-" (minus) below to remove it from the list.

Comment: It was never in Apps -> Startup.

Comment: what about into `.config/autostart` do you have any pantheon-mail .desktop files?

Comment: That was it for me.